# Migrating Google Analytics complete raw session data (all 290 fields) to an AWS s3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-analytics, amazon-redshift, analytics

Any idea/related resource on how to migrate Google Analytics raw session/hit level data, then dump in an AWS s3 bucket?

I have tried a couple of technologies, but they are limited. AWS AppFlow for instance is limited to only 9 fields to migrate. The Google Analytics API V4 as well is limited to just custom dimension/metrics, thus cannot export the whole data in its raw format.

Feedback appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy Google Analytics 360 (~150k/year) then connect the view you want to BigQuery. So it will provide a historical export of the smaller of 10 billion hits or 13 months of data within 4 weeks after the integration is complete (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en).

There are no other solutions to have the complete raw data.